# Регулярное выражение для поиска одного слова (на русском)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel

Не удается построить регулярное выражение для поиска определённых слов записанных на кириллице. 
Например для поиска вот таких слов:

- Сем Алт
- Поиск**
- Арт

в строке типа:

- Номер Эврика R1 5вт Seminis Сем Алт

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:
чтобы найти слова в ячейках Excel, необходимо вызвать редактор Visual Basic с вкладки Разработчик (Developer) или сочетанием клавиш Alt+F11. Затем вставеть новый модуль через меню Insert - Module и скопировать туда текст вот такой макрофункции:

```
Public Function RegExpExtract(Text As String, Pattern As String, Optional Item As Integer = 1) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = Pattern
    regex.Global = True
    If regex.Test(Text) Then
        Set matches = regex.Execute(Text)
        RegExpExtract = matches.Item(Item - 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
ErrHandl:
    RegExpExtract = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

после использовать формулу начинающуюся с =RegExpExtract.
Регулярное выражение при этом будет такого типа:

```
\П\о\и\с\к\*\*
```

или

```
\С\е\м\s\А\л\т
```

Comment: Но Вам же нужно  было несколько слов искать? И какой смысл в таких регулярках, когда нужно указывать посимвольно одно слово или фразу? Гораздо легче искать целое слово, без использования регулярных выражений.